# Data manipulation in Pandas Dataframe add row for each group

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I would like to do data manipulation for below data. I want to add another row below for each manager where the manager and the worker is the same.
How can I do that?

Not:Everything for manager would be same for worker. This is just a sample scenario for my data set
Thank you.

```
   data = [['Tom','Aurora',4500,'Shelly','Chicago',43553]
    ,['Tom','Aurora',4500,'Alex','NewYork',43654]
    ,['Tom','Aurora',4500,'Kelly','Cincinnati',44674]
    ,['Jason','Charlotte',4567,'Jimmy','Boston',44984]
    ,['Jason','Charlotte',4567,'Aaron','Austin',44583]
   ]

   # Create the pandas DataFrame 
   df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Manager','Managercity', 
   'manager_id','Worker','WorkerCity','Worker_id']) 

   # print dataframe. 
   print(df)
```

Desired dataset below

```
 Manager Managercity  manager_id  Worker  WorkerCity  Worker_id
    Tom      Aurora        4500  Shelly     Chicago      43553
    Tom      Aurora        4500    Alex     NewYork      43654
    Tom      Aurora        4500   Kelly  Cincinnati      44674
    Tom      Aurora        4500     Tom      Aurora       4500
  Jason   Charlotte        4567   Jimmy      Boston      44984
  Jason   Charlotte        4567   Aaron      Austin      44583
  Jason   Charlotte        4567   Jason   Charlotte       4567
```

Thank you

Comment: Please edit data frame creation because there is no lines where manager name == worker name.. I'm not even sure to understand you'r question. You want to create the 4th lines? if yes, how do you define **worker city** since we don't know **Tom City**...

Comment: The same should add to the worker and WorkerCity and Worker_id

Comment: You input dataframe and desired dataframe are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```py
def add(gr):
    new_row = gr.iloc[0,:]
    new_row['Worker'] = new_row['Manager']
    new_row['Worker_id'] = new_row['manager_id']
    return gr.append(new_row)
df = df.groupby('Manager').apply(add).reset_index(drop = True)
```

Your sample data doesn't contain `ManagerCity`, but you could set it too using `new_row['Worker_city'] = new_row['Manager_city']` on add function.

Comment: Sorry man I edited the data set your function gives me an error KeyError: 'Manager'

Comment: @melik you should really stick either to upper or lower case on your column names, it's confusing otherwise, considering the error, you should just change the names like `Worker, Manager` on my code  as you defined them on your data so you won't get an error

Comment: glad I helped, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pd.concat` and `drop duplicates` like this:

```
data = [['Tom','Aurora',4500,'Shelly','Chicago',43553]
    ,['Tom','Aurora',4500,'Alex','NewYork',43654]
    ,['Tom','Aurora',4500,'Kelly','Cincinnati',44674]
    ,['Jason','Charlotte',4567,'Jimmy','Boston',44984]
    ,['Jason','Charlotte',4567,'Aaron','Austin',44583]
   ]

   # Create the pandas DataFrame 
df_in = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Manager','Managercity', 'manager_id','Worker','WorkerCity','Worker_id']) 

df_managers = pd.DataFrame(np.tile(df_in[['Manager','Managercity','manager_id']].drop_duplicates(),2),columns=df_in.columns)
df_out = pd.concat([df_in, df_managers]).sort_values('Manager').reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
  Manager Managercity manager_id  Worker  WorkerCity Worker_id
0   Jason   Charlotte       4567   Jimmy      Boston     44984
1   Jason   Charlotte       4567   Aaron      Austin     44583
2   Jason   Charlotte       4567   Jason   Charlotte      4567
3     Tom      Aurora       4500  Shelly     Chicago     43553
4     Tom      Aurora       4500    Alex     NewYork     43654
5     Tom      Aurora       4500   Kelly  Cincinnati     44674
6     Tom      Aurora       4500     Tom      Aurora      4500
```